# animated responsive background image grid

Tags: grid, background-image, responsive-images

I am trying to make [THIS GRID](http://www.uzairusman.com/test/) responsive vertically.

Horizontally it is responsive, takes full width. But if the page is long, image grid doesn't take full height.

Any suggestions?
Please see attached the screen-shot of current result.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbgnN.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please include a screenshot in the post, a link can go dead in the future, making the question useless for future viewers ! Make sure to also include some code you got so far, so that people can check what is wrong with the solution you got

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it through JavaScript and resize the element to cover the window height, so use this function to retrieve the height and set that to your div height dynamically:

`$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport`

In case you need more information

```
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```